# Notification with sound and vibration when iphone is Locked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am currently working on an iOS app and i need some help.

I want the app to be able to notify the user about something in form a "push notification" even when the phone locked. The push notifications work fine when the phone is not locked but as soon as i lock the phone it wont give me any sound or vibration. It will only show me the visual part of the notification but it comes in completely silence. It does not even light the screen up when the notification gets pushed to the user.

I currently use

```
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

And it works fine with sound and vibration when the phone is unlocked.

Is it because i need to do something with my settings? do i need any code to do such thing? do i need to have developer account?

Any help would make me really happy!!

Comment: What does you configuration look in your AppDelegate for notifications?

Comment: Im not sure how to answer your question, im not that experienced. The only thing i did/coded to create notifications was 1. import UserNotifications 2. create the requestAuthorization 3. create the notification with let content = UNMutableNotificationContent() 4. Create the trigger and the request... 

Im not sure about configuration of AppDelegate for notifications

Comment: Double check your Notification settings (Apple Settings App -> Notifications).

Comment: The settings on my iphone are all correct and everything is enabled. I find it really wierd becuase my appleWatch actually vibrates when the notification is pushed?!?... just not my iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 STEPS TO HOPEFULLY RECOVER SOUND ON YOUR IPHONE FOR INCOMING NOTIFICATIONS.

Check that the ringer on the left of the phone doesn’t show an orange line – indicating sound switched off. If so, slide it to the right so only white is showing. This may have fixed it.

Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to reveal symbols, music etc. Ensure that the half moon symbol is grey and not white. If it’s white touch it to make it grey – this will switch off do not disturb. This may have fixed it.

Check your settings, Do not Disturb half moon icon, ensure that Manual is off and not showing a green on icon. If it is, touch the green icon which will make it white and switch it off. This may have fixed it.

(I hope that helps, it worked for my iphone 5C as I’d inadvertently switched on Do Not disturb as shown in step 2. above.)

Comment: I think you are right. I just noticed that every single app is silenced when my phone is locked, not just mine. Your help cleared things up! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI if someone else is having this same issue. I was having the same troubles getting my notifications to come through on my phone when it was locked.

I realized the issue was I was building to my physical device which was also attached to the Apple Watch I was wearing. Since my watch is set to mirror my iPhone notifications the phone didn't play them as it expected my watch to take over when was locked. However, every time you build & run your app it takes a few minutes for your watch to recognize your app and take over the user notifications.

The solution here is to either wait 10 minutes or so after building and then try firing off a notification (which should appear on your watch) OR simple take off your watch before you build & run.